# The socket connection was aborted in wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, sockets, nettcpbinding

i had created dynamic endpoint in server side and that endpoint used by client side.

Server side Code:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(PokerService.IPlayerService),
                                               new NetTcpBinding(),
                                               @"net.tcp://localhost:5054/player" + i);

            }
```

Client side:

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Message);
binding.Name = "NetTcpBinding_IPlayerService";
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.IssuedToken;


EndpointAddress myEndpointAdd = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:5054/player1"),
EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("pident.cloudapp.net"));

var PlayerChannelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<ClientApplication.PlayerService.IPlayerService>(new PlayerHandler(handler, this), binding, myEndpointAdd);
```

but it give error in this following line :

```
Player loggedIn = PlayerServiceProxy.Login("testuser" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

The error is:

"The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.9870000'."

have anyone idea?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like timeout. Review your client and service timeouts configuration.

Also, try to use svcTraceViewer.exe to review wcf trace